# Simulating dataset in R

Tags: r, vector, dataset, simulation

I am trying to simulate a dataset and am a bit stuck on the following, as I'm a bit new to R. Here's the code I have so far:

```
set.seed(10)
n <- 300
x1a <- rnorm(100,1,2)
x1b <- rnorm(100,0,1)
x1c <- rnorm(100,1,0.5)
x1 <- c(x1a,x1b,x1c)
x2a <- rnorm(100,1,2)
x2b <- rnorm(100,1,1)
x2c <- rnorm(100,0,0.5)
x2 <- c(x2a,x2b,x2c)
```

This is what I wanted to create:

Dataset with 300 observations and three variables: x1, x2 and g.

g has 3 levels, with lvl 1 having observations 1-100, lvl2 having obs 101-200, and lvl 3 having obs 201-300.

x1 and x2 have the following factors:

the first 100 obs have mean 1 for x1, mean 1 for x2, sd of 2 for both;

the second 100 obs have mean 0 for x1, mean 1 for x2, sd of 1 for both;

the third 100 obs have mean 1 for x1, mean 0 for x2, sd of 0.5 for both.

I was able to create the first two vectors, x1 and x2 in my code above. However, when creating g, I'm not sure where to begin and how to incorporate that into the dataset. I am also not sure on how to combine everything to generate only one vector with the full 300 observations including all of these factors.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `rep` i.e. `g <- rep(paste0('lv', 1:3), each=100)`